# How to allocate array of classes with a constructor that takes parameters?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, mfc

Say, I declare my C++ class (used in Visual Studio 2008) as such:

```
enum FLAGS{
    FLAG1 = 0x1
};

//.h
class CMyClass
{
public:
    CRecycleBinOps(FLAGS flags);
private:
    FLAGS _flags;
};
```

and then the implementation:

```
//.cpp
CMyClass::CMyClass(FLAGS flags) : 
    _flags(flags)
{
    //Only this constructor is acceptable
}
```

When I try to allocate an array of my CMyClass:

```
CMyClass* pArr = new (std::nothrow) CMyClass[n];
```

It gives me the following error because I'm not passing the input parameter to the class:

```
error C2512: 'CMyClass' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

So how do I pass the parameter in that form?